# Is it possible to debug 2 programs in Eclipse at the same time?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Everything is in the question. I wrote an UDP server/client and I want to debug both of them when the client sends a request to the server. 
How can I achieve that !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible I do this all the time, when doing messaging based applications. Run each of your programs in debug mode, and make sure you are in the debug perspective where you will be able to see both apps in Debug view and can place break points.

If the client and server are running on different machines you will need to use remote debugging, which will require you to start the JVM with the remote debug options, and you will have to edit the run configuration for your client and server to enable remote debugging, check the eclipse help for the steps needed to setup remote debugging.

Comment: You can see two active processes with each their own threads etc.

Answer (score 1):

Very much possible. Just set you breakpoints for both projects and run both. You'll see two programs running in the console and in the thread tree view.

Answer (score 0):

right click with mouse...
"debug as"
"java application"..

do it 2 times on different java files..